# a positive potential as $ x \rightarrow \infty $

Tags: schroedinger-equation, potential

let us suppose i can calculate the asymptotic of any potential $ V(x) $ in one dimension , and that i manage to prove that $ V(x) \ge 0 $ as $ x \rightarrow \infty $

could i conclude taht if or big 'x' the potential is POSITIVE that for big 'n' the enegies will be also POSITIVE $ E_{n} \ge 0 $ ?? as $ n \rightarrow \infty $

the idea is that if we define a turning point $ E=V(a) $ and 'a' is a turning point then if a is very big for big energy E then V(a) will be also positive but this is just in the WKB approximation isn't it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) It seems that the question(v1) is essentially asking the following:

> *If a 1D potential $V$ is a non-negative function on the real line $\mathbb{R}$, except for a compact interval $[a,b]$ where it is allowed to be negative, then would the number of (bounded) negative energy eigenstates for the corresponding 1D Hamiltonian $$H(x,p)~=~\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)$$ 
>   always be finite?*

The answer is in general *No.*

*Counterexample:*

$$V(x) ~=~ V_0 - \frac{A}{|x|^p},$$

where $V_0>0$ and $A>0$ are positive constants, and the power $p>2$. It is possible to prove that the spectrum is unbounded from below with infinitely many negative energy eigenstates in a very similar to e.g. methods used in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24826/2451) Phys.SE answer.

II)

> *What if one additionally assumes that the potential $V$ is bounded from below?*

Then the answer is *Yes,* because there must exist positive constants $V_0,L>0$ such that 
$$V(x)~\geq~ -V_0 ~\theta(L\!-\!|x|) .$$ 
In other words, one can find a [finite potential well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) with lower energy levels, but we know that the spectrum of a finite potential well satisfies the sought-for statement.

III)

> *What if one instead only additionally assumes that the spectrum (but not necessarily the potential $V$) is bounded from below, i.e. that the system has a stable ground state?*

Then the answer is *Yes,* semiclassically (WKB), and I believe it is *Yes* non-semiclassically as well, but I don't (yet) have a rigorous proof.

Comment: thanks Qmechanic what would happen if the potential $ V(x)=x^{2}- \frac{A}{|x|^{p}}$ for big 'x' would the energies be the ones of the harmonic oscillator ??