# Particle in a higher-dimensional box with an attractive delta potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, dirac-delta-distributions

Suppose you have a particle in the box $[0,L]^d$, with an attractive Dirac delta potential $-\delta_{\vec w}(x)$ at $\vec w$. How do you solve the Schroedinger equation for this system?

In the case $d=1$, you know your solutions are linear combinations of $e^{ikx}$ and $e^{-ikx}$. If you assume that you have two different linear combinations on $[0,w]$ and $[w,L]$, you have four coefficients you need to find. You can enforce the vanishing at the endpoints of the interval, continuity at $w$, and the discontinuity in the first derivative that you get from integrating across $w$, in order to get enough conditions on the coefficients to be able to find the quantization condition for $k$, and then solve for the coefficients.

However, for $d>1$, this doesn't work -- the delta potential doesn't divide the box into disjoint pieces. What do you do?

Comment: Comment to the question (v4): Beware that in too high dimensions the Hamiltonian is not bounded from below and the mathematical problem is therefore ill-defined, cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24009/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Related post by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90049/2451

Comment: That link refers to the delta potential well on all of R^3. Does the result hold if the system is a box?

Comment: What's mathematically wrong with a Hamiltonian whose spectrum is unbounded from below?

Comment: Mathematically nothing might be wrong, but physically you get infinite binding energy for the ground state. And, AFAIR, the energy gap is also infinite there, so your system would be unexcitable — i.e. really unphysical.